# how to validate the already registered user in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have made the registration page using spring mvc. So far I am able to register and login. But I want to check if the user has already registered with username,email and phone number. To do the same i tried to do that in the DAO layer using if else but it did't worked at all. the query I tried is this:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE username = 'bruceb' and email='bruce@gmail.com' and phone = 1234566;
```

So please tell me the right way to validate the user while doing the regstration.

this the my dao query for registration:

```
public int register(User user) {
String sql = "insert into user values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { user.getUser_id(),user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getFirstname(),
    user.getLastname(), user.getEmail(), user.getAddress(), user.getPhone() });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think that query it's quite right, basically, your search for a user that has that exact username, email, and phone number. I suggest using the "or" operator and you can do a simple validation here. You can make that query to count how many users have that credentials and use them like

```
if(queryResult == 0){
  register(user);
else{
 //try again
}
```